# one monitor between Mac and PC

Tags: mac

My dual input monitor allows me to share itself between a Mac and a PC. I can switch between the Mac and the PC by using the "input control" on the monitor. If I set the monitor to the Mac input (DVI) and leave the Mac unattended (no keyboard or mouse activity) after awhile the monitor switches over to the PC (VGA)

1. What is causing that?
2. How do I stop it from happening?

Bill

Comment: What is the model of the monitor? Is it set to auto-select the inputs or auto-switch or auto-anything regarding the inputs?

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: If you use the same (Mac) keyboard and mouse for both computers (which I do), you might want to get KeyTweak for Windows.  Then you can map the Command key to the Alt key, which feels more natural when you're on the PC.  You can map volume keys, PrintScreen, etc, that way too.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the Mac goes into a screen saver that switches off the monitor after a while. Most monitors will search automatically search for an active input (which will be your PC). Some monitors may just switch on the first input, if no input is active. That all depends a bit on what monitor you have.

You should be able to tweak the screensaver of your Mac to be sure that it never blanks the screen. That will most probably prevent the undesired behaviour.

Comment: You also might be able to find a setting in the monitor to turn off that "searching" feature.  My monitor doesn't have that (thankfully), so it's always on whatever input I left it, but you can definitely disable the Mac's screen-power-off function or possibly disable the monitor's searching feature.

Comment: Thanks to all who answered! Don't know why I didn't think of it but the Mac's screensaver was the problem.